# use Django views and DRF views together

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django REST Framework. i describe my question with a example.

for example, i have a api view function that can handle GET method and return a list of Users in json. the url of this api is www.exp.com/api/users

now i want a view that get list of Users, send them to a template and render the template. the url of this view is www.exp.com/users

logics of above views are same.
how can i do like above example?
should i write two seprate view (api and django view)?

Comment: Use code with your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Django** to render front-end pages than you need to write two views. Otherwise, you can use other front-end technologies for rendering front-end pages such as [React.js](https://reactjs.org/), [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/), [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) and so on.

You can use generic [`ListAPIView`](http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.generics/ListAPIView.html) for listing users.

You could refer to [Classy Django Rest Framework](http://www.cdrf.co/) for more class based `APIViews`.